# Dealing with arbitrary figure sizes: achieving consistent font size

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, fontsize, ieeetran, journal

I created numerous figures (approximately 100) for a research article using various tools like TikZ, MatLab, and Visio. One mistake I made initially was not considering the paper size, column width, while creating the figures. Consequently, I ended up with figures of arbitrary sizes. When inserting these figures into the paper, I simply used the `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images}` command to fit them within the column width.

The problem with this approach is that the font size varies significantly across the figures. Now, I have been instructed to ensure consistency in the font and font size for all of my figures. Unfortunately, recreating all the figures within the given time frame is not feasible.

I am curious if anyone has encountered a similar situation and found a suitable solution. One possible approach I have considered is examining the scale factor of each figure and subsequently resizing the font, proportionally larger or smaller, using the same factor to achieve a consistent font size for all figures in the paper.

Does this proposed method sound reasonable?